# Any performance difference between Ubuntu desktop and server versions?

Tags: dual-boot, server

I am planning on setting a server which will be running 24/7, for educational purposes mainly. The machine will also serve as a HTPC occasionally since it will be connected to my TV.

That being said i am wondering if there is any significant performance loss or/and resources usage between the desktop and server versions.

PS. I know i can just dual boot and install windows but i'd rather stick with just one OS if the performance is not that big of a deal

thanks in advance

Comment: Any desktop requires resources, and those are resources that are not available for other functions (eg. memory useful for caching disk allowing faster ...)   so yes there will be a performance hit if a server is also running a desktop.  Your usage case (+ hardware) will dictate how significant that performance loss will be.